# Errors not caught by Global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, global-asax

My project has an error page called oops.aspx.  We have the following code in `global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer("~/oops.aspx", true);
}
```

`oops.aspx` is able to extract the error, generate a nice email to the server, and present an error message to the user.

The use of `Server.Transfer` preserves the URL, form information, and other helpful troubleshooting information.  At one point in the oops.aspx, while composing the email, I grab Request.RawUrl and include it in the email.  This is the URL (with query string parameters) of the page that caused the error.

We also have this in web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="oops.aspx"></customErrors>
```

When the system redirects because of an error based on this, it redirects to `/oops.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/Clients/EditClient.aspx` (sometimes with /, sometimes with %2f path separators).  Querystring and Exception information is lost, so the email and messages generated by oops.aspx are sparse and don't say much about what was happening.

I've been getting a lot of errors of this second kind lately.  The errors happen in small bunches, several of them in a few minutes, and then nothing for several hours.  They happen all over the site (including on `WebResource.axd` and the like), which makes me think that it's not a specific error in our site but something happening at a lower level, like a Session server issue or something like that.

So, with all that, my actual question:

I'm having errors in the site that happen in such a way that they are not caught by global.asax.  What can cause such errors, and how can I troubleshoot them?

Answer (score 6):

Since you have enabled custom errors in your web.config, the exception will be caught before the Application_Error executes and redirect you to `oops.aspx`. If you don't want this from happening do not enable custom errors in your web.config. This way all errors will go through `Application_Error` assuming you have configured IIS to run the application pool in Integrated pipeline mode.

Comment: Darin what's the relationship with `Application_Error` and app pool being in Integrated Pipeline mode?

Comment: @VoodooChild, if you run in classic mode in IIS 6.0 when someone tries to access for example `/myapp/foo.jpg`, the Application_Error will never be hit. ASP.NET won't even be notified of this request. IIS will directly serve the image. In integrated pipeline mode, all requests go through a managed handler.